Installed MariaDB, databases backed up, but .frm files missing
So I made the mistake of installing MariaDB without backing up my old stuff. Sorry, you guys.
But while I've seen other posts about how to restore the databases, they so far have not worked:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/941756/accidentally-installed-mariadb-over-mysql-how-do-i-recover-my-mysql-databases
The additional ripple in my case is that the backed up folders don't seem to contain the .frm files that I see in the new MariaDB databases. Is that a problem? I have no idea how the system could have backed up one and not the other?
Thanks in advance.
